При выполнении команды git fetch через jenkins не обновляется ветка
Настроил jenkins на запуск скрипта, который выкатывает ветку на хостинге. Но если ветки еще не было на хостинге, только запушили в репозиторий, то скрипт не работает. Выполняется команда git fetch через скрипт, но ветка не появляется. После git fetch следует команда переключения на новую ветку, но выводится ошибка, что таковой нет.
В чем может быть причина? .git/config настроен

как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример

В конфиге есть параметр remote.origin.fetch, если у него значение +refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master, а не +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*, то fetch будет обрабатывать только ветку master

Если после git fetch выполнить git branch -a, есть ли ветка в remotes/origin?

@Герман-Борисов в конфиге +refs/heads/:refs/remotes/origin/

@pak-uula, пробовал так, все равно ветку не видит. Очень странная проблема, уже многие ресурсы облазил и никак не могу решить этот вопрос.
